# How get an SQL output cursor into a Delphi Data Component?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, cursor, varying

I have a stored procedure with this signature:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SI_Inteligence(@dt datetime, @actions varchar(6), @FullData cursor varying out)
```

This procedure returns an open cursor.

What kind of component do I need to trap it and iterate over it record by record? It's only a parameter from stored procedure!

```
procedure DoIt;
var sp: TADOStoredProc;
    x: TADODataSet; //?
begin
  sp               := TADOStoredProc.Create(Self);
  sp.Connection    := myConnection; //TADOConnection Component
  sp.ProcedureName := 'SI_Inteligence';
  sp.Parameters.ParamByName('@dt').Value      := date;
  sp.Parameters.ParamByName('@actions').Value := 'something';
  sp.ExecProc;//? Open doesn't return anything
  x := TADODataSet.Create(Self);
  //How load the cursor??
  x.Assign(sp.Parameters.ParamByName('@FullData') as TADODataSet); //crash

end;
```

Now I need loop that cursor. How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you returning the data in a cursor and not as a result set? Also which version of Delphi?

Comment: Use TADOQuery and EXEC statement

Comment: This is only an example. My real sp returns 4 cursors. I am using Delphi XE 3

Answer (score 4):

The CURSOR params are returned as recordsets, So you can iterate over the data using the `TADOStoredProc` methods related to the `TDataSet` class like `Eof`, `Next`, `FieldByName` and so on.

Try this code .

```
  ADOStoredProc1.ExecProc;
  while not ADOStoredProc1.Eof do
  begin
    //do something 
    //ADOStoredProc1.FieldByName('Foo').Value;    
    ADOStoredProc1.Next;
  end;
```

if the stored procedure return more than a cursor, you can iterate over the recordsets using the [`NextRecordset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677539(VS.85).aspx) method as is described on this [post](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/returning-multiple-datasets-with-ado-and-delphi/).

Comment: When assign "SI_Inteligence" sp to AdoStoredProc1.ProcedureName, the component populates all params. It creates the cursor corresponding one as "Integer". If change to ftCursor or ftDataSet the "Incorrect arguments, out of range or in conflict with other" messege raises... and the ExecProc doesn´t run.